# Chipmunk for Cocos2D, Collision Detection - Best Practice?

Tags: iphone, ipad, cocos2d-iphone, collision-detection, chipmunk

I'm using Chipmunk physics and want to do collision detection to find out when 2 cpBodies collide. I've got some questions;

- Could you give me an example of using [cpCollPairFunc](http://digitus.itk.ppke.hu/~gonma/teszt/cpp/doxygen_EV_gameMaster/html/structcp_coll_pair_func.html) or cpSpaceAddCollisionHandler ?
- I've seen around the rectangle intersection; is that possible for polygons?
- Should I use another library (SpaceManager or whatever) on top?

Thank you!

F.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Joe thank you for your response; Corona is not freeware isn't it.

The saviour at the end was: 
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/9425 and the [cpSpaceAddCollisionHandler](http://code.google.com/p/chipmunk-physics/wiki/CallbackSystem) method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add following lines

> shape->collision_type  = kCollisionTypeParticle;
>   cpSpaceAddCollisionHandler(space_, kCollisionTypeParticle, kCollisionTypeParticle, collisonDetect, NULL, NULL, NULL, self);

kCollisionTypeParticle is enum you can define it if there are two types of different particles.

> typedef enum {
>            kCollisionTypeParticle,
>            kCollisionTypeParticleNew
>   } CollisionType;

Here collisonDetect is a method we need to register as:

> cpBool collisonDetect(cpArbiter *arb, struct cpSpace *space, void *data) 
>   {
>         *layer = ( *)data;
>        [layer collisonDetect:arb];
>        return cpTrue;
>   }

Now here here you will handle rest of the code

> -(void)collisonDetect:(cpArbiter*)arb
>   {
>           NSLog(@"COLLISION DETECTED");
>   }

Comment: You're pasting the same answer over and over on a multitude of questions. If you're going to be doing that, at least go through the 'bother' of learning how to properly format code. Look at the buttons in the editor, learn what EACH does, and what the RESULT of each is.

Comment: Thank you Steen I'll do that :)